# Upload file in Django and nginx with jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, django, nginx

I'm using jquery file upload in Django and it run well with command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but when I config this run with nginx and fastcgi I got an error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
```

And here is my config in nginx:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name mysite.local;
access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log;
client_max_body_size 50M;

location /static/ { # STATIC_URL
    alias /home/username/workspace/python_env/myprojectname/assets/;
    #expires 30d;
}

location /media/ { # MEDIA_URL
    alias /home/username/workspace/python_env/myprojectname/media/;
    #expires 30d;
}

location / {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^()(.*)$;
}
```

}

I'm upload images and another file to folder:

```
"/assets/uploads/"
```

I'm newbie in both Python Django and Nginx so I wish someone could help me some advantage direction. Thank you for reading my post!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, starting the django process using:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

is not recommended. See (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/). Instead you want to start the process using:

```
python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8080 --settings=settings
```

This will start a fastcgi process that nginx can pass requests through to.

Secondly, you have to make sure that the above process has read and write access to `assets/uploads`

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: thank you Matthew Brown for your direction! I will check permission for this process and post a result as soon as possible.

Comment: even though I change permission using this command: sudo chown a+w username:www-data my folder and I still got an error permission denied. I guest I may put my folder to another folder not under /home/

Comment: Is your MEDIA_ROOT set to /home/username/workspace/python_env/myprojectname/media/ and MEDIA_URL to http://mysite.local/media/

Comment: yeah I set media_url exactly like you write above, Matthew Brown.  I mean in settings.py in my project. And in nginx conf I set alias the same. Do you have any ideal for this my setting. tks alot!

Comment: Random idea: what happens is you run the python process as root? Does it work then?

Comment: Also is this http://i.imgur.com/6IvzTnQ.png the error you're are getting? If so I'm convinced that it's a permissions error.
Maybe try running `chown -R username:www-data /home/username/workspace/python_env/myprojectname` and then `chmod -R +rw /home/username/workspace/python_env/myprojectname`